# Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: apache, osx-yosemite

I upgraded to yosemite and now apache won't start.  Ive seen a lot of people having the same issue but none of the fixes they mention seem to work.

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

Answer (score -1):

I am linux apache user and there are few things I noticed.

```
127.0.0.1          localhost
255.255.255.255.   broadcasthost
::1                localhost
fe80::1%lo0        localhost
```

should be like this as this is my signature settings

```
127.0.0.1          localhost.localdomain localhost
255.255.255.0      broadcasthost
## not 255.255.255.255 as we are defining Apache the netmask
::1                localhost.localdomain localhost
fe80::1%lo0        localhost.localdomain localhost
```

`localhost.localdomain localhost`  enables Apache to look up and finding your hosts on your LAN OR via DNS (DNS check requires the string of `localhost.domain.com`.  So, for loopback for either host or hostname (`local` or `local.mydomain.com`) queries, this will set the system with this format `localhost.localdomain`.  Real time example:   one of my 7 servers host name is `X7` and my domain, `faron.ca`.  So with this it'd be like this:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1  mail
127.0.1.2  X7
127.0.122.1 space

192.168.125.7   mail.faron.ca
192.168.7.127   X7.faron.ca  faron.ca  cloud.faron.ca  faronhost.ca 
192.168.122.1   space.faron.ca   # this is virtual bridge LAN

 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
 ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
 ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: I see...I am going to go ahead and upgrade to Yosemite on VM and if I manage to get it working, I'll post here.

Comment: For ServerName, always use the full qualifiy domain address without port.  Port is already defined by machine.  Edit to `ServerName localhost` but, I often notice tricky area when using `localhost`.  If you insist on using `localhost` then use `127.0.0.1` instead.  It should stop the error message.

Comment: thanks again, still nothing though.  Would you mind diff'ing this for me? https://gist.github.com/cmillsLA/d83837a89254539ea827

Comment: Ive been going through all these of these with several docs and a friends machine,

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

/etc/hosts, 
are there any other files that would affect ServerName?